# Foundation pop up is not closing on call of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, zurb-foundation

The problem that we are having is closing the Foundation for apps popup when the 'give feedback' button is clicked.

```
            <a class="align-center app-student-icon"
               zf-popup-toggle="{{'popup-' + $index}}">
                <span ng-bind="getMemberById(assessment.user).fullname"></span>
                <i class="icon icon-pencil-no-fill"></i>
            </a>
            <zf-popup id="{{'popup-' + $index}}" class="padding text-center">
                <h5>Question Feedback</h5>
                <textarea name="name"
                          rows="4"
                          placeholder="Leave feedback here"
                          ng-model="assessment.test.tutorFeedback"></textarea>
                <button type="submit"
                        class="button expand"
                        ng-click="closeAndSavePopup('popup-' + $index, assessment)">Give feedback</button>
            </zf-popup>
```

The 'Give Feedback' button triggers the below scope function:

```
    scope.closeAndSavePopup = function (popupId, object) {
        saveFeedback(object);

        setTimeout(function () {
            FoundationApi.closeActiveElements();
        });
    };
```

We've dependency injected the foundationApi so we can access the module functions foundation has given us. We have used the example above as well as

> FoundationApi.publish(popupId, 'close')

However when clicked the foundation popup doesn't seem to want to close. We have also used toggle instead of close to see if this would make a difference.

Has anyone else come into this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the foundation code we realised that this was a bug/poor documentation of our version of foundation for apps.

The answer is to wrap the 'close' in square brackets.

> FoundationApi.publish(popupId, ['close'])

The reason being is because in the foundation javascript it is expecting a array for popups and pretty much anything else a string.. So stupid..

cheers